# Trigger pipeline upon approval in Azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have a report which generate after running an ADF pipeline, and I would need to append these records into a history table upon client approval. So, I need to use either PowerBi or Sharepoint to show this report to the client and get approval. So, I have this plan, Can someone please tell me if this is doable, if yes, how to achieve it? if not please suggest changes.

1. Show the report in either PowerBI or SharePoint, and have buttons Approve/Reject.
2. If the client clicks on Approve, it should trigger a pipeline using the Logic app, with necessary parameters passed.

if this is doable, can you please share the references?  if not, please let me know how i achieve this functionality in another way.

Comment: Clientside sharepoint is call from a SharePoint workflow linked to your form then to your logic apps endpoint. U can’t use key though setup a app identity for SharePoint to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround to achieve your requirement is to use logic apps and send the PowerBI or SharePoint link using email with `Send approval email` action of outlook connector where the email is send with Approval or Reject user options.

[image]

The flow is kept on hold until the the response is received.

[image]

**In my outlook**

[image]

Run after response is received

[image]

Now to continue the flow if you receive accepted response, You can add condition action and check if the response is Approved and then continue the flow.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is the codeview of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "Your response have been Accepted.",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@body('Send_approval_email')?['SelectedOption']",
                                "Approve"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Send_approval_email": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Send_approval_email": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Message": {
                            "Body": "https://microsoftapc.sharepoint.com/teams/Sample2408/Lists/SampleList/AllItems.aspx",
                            "HideHTMLMessage": false,
                            "Importance": "Normal",
                            "Options": "Approve, Reject",
                            "ShowHTMLConfirmationDialog": false,
                            "Subject": "Approval Request",
                            "To": "<Email_ID>"
                        },
                        "NotificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/approvalmail/$subscriptions"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Sub_Id>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Sub_Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write this answer.